WPF - Change treeview selection colors
I am interested in changing the background and foreground of all treeview selected item
Looking at this page for reference
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/treeview-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8
I tried this but it does not seem to work
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Border x:Name="Bd"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header"
                                      ContentSource="Header"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Panel.Background" Value="green"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="BorderBrush" Value="red"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Panel.Background" Value="yellow"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="BorderBrush" Value="magenta"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

Any help appreciated
[edit]
I tried
<!-- Define the style for the TreeViewItem -->
<Style x:Name="MyTreeViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="green"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="red"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource MyTreeViewItemStyle}" />
</Style>


You need to set the ItemContainerStyle for the TreeView, either directly or in a separate style.
<Style x:Name="MyTreeViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        ...
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource MyTreeViewItemStyle}" />
</Style>


sorry but this is not clear, I get "MyTreeViewItemStyle could not be resolved" while defined just above

You have to give your style for TreeViewItem a name as in my example.

I tried, I added it to my question

You must have incompatible styles being set elsewhere then. That code is a copy of my standard TreeView style https://github.com/Peregrine66/PeregrinesView/blob/master/library/Peregrine.WPF.View/Styles/TreeViewStyle.xaml as featured in my blog post http://peregrinesview.uk/wpf-behaviors-part-2-treeview/

does not look like a conflict, I mean the style is defined right above it, seems like an API issue, it is an old project, maybe that syntax was not allowed or something

TreeViewItem uses static resources for its colors. I believes these ones may apply to you:
<Color x:Key="SelectedBackgroundColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="SelectedUnfocusedColor">#FFDDDDDD</Color>

<Color x:Key="PressedBorderLightColor">#FF888888</Color>
<Color x:Key="PressedBorderDarkColor">#FF444444</Color>

In your XAML, define your own static Color resources, using the same "Keys". This will then override the colors in the TreeViewItem
